# Php перенаправление на предыдущую страницу

Tags: php

Есть такие скрипты, которые обрабатывают данные, а потом нужно вернуться на предыдущую страницу, делаю через

```
 public static function GoBack() {
        if (@$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] != null) {
            header("Location: ".$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
        }
        Sys::GoHome();
    }
```

но всегда срабатывает Sys::GoHome();

что тут может быть не так?

Comment: добавьте после header(...) return.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нашёл,

```
if (...) {
    header("Location: ".$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
}
Sys::GoHome();
```

Оказывается после `header()`, выполнение продолжается, надо было писать через else

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте использовать после функции `header($str);` функцию завершающую выполнения php скрипта `exit();`